# The integration of a form on the smooth locus of an analytic subvariety

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

Let $X$ be a compact complex manifold, and $V$ be an irreducible analytic subvariety of $X$. Denote $V_{reg}$ the set of regular points of $V$, or the smooth locus of $V$, suppose $V_{reg}$ is of dimension $k$, and $\alpha$ is a smooth real $(k,k)$ form on $X$, then I was told that we can integrate $\alpha$ with respect to $V$.

The logic here is clear. $V_{reg}$ is well-known to be a complex submanifold, and $\alpha$ is a top form on $V_{reg}$. However, it seems to me that $\alpha$ is not necessarily compactly supported on $V_{reg}$, how is the integration well-defined then?

Comment: Note that $X$ is compact and $\alpha$ is smooth on $X$.

Comment: is it necessarily true that $\alpha$ compactly supported on $V_{reg}$?

Comment: No, that's not going to be true, but why would you need that when $\alpha$ is smooth on all of $X$?

Comment: To my knowledge if I am going to integrate a top form I need either my manifold to be compact or my form to be compactly supported.

Comment: The key thing that is special about complex geometry is that the singular sets of complex subvarieties have real codimension $\ge 2$. So $V_{\text{reg}}$ has locally finite volume (see, for example, pp. 32-33 of Griffiths/Harris).

Comment: Sorry, I am confused. Let me be more explicit. From smooth manifold, theory, if I want to integrate a top form $\omega$ on a maniofld $M$, we need either $\omega$ to be compactly supported or $M$ to be compact. Here, we are trying to integrate $\alpha$ on $V_{reg}$, but how is that well-defined without further assumptions?

Comment: You’re just repeating yourself and ignoring what I said is pertinent in the case of complex subvarieties. You need to learn some new stuff.

Comment: I see. Now I get it, the reason that we want our form to be compactly supported is that we need to ensure locally the integration is finite. Now if we are on a compact manifold, then the form is 'bounded'. So together with the fact that we have bounded volume then the finiteness is automatic without further assumption.